# Node js копирование с ncp - UNC путь

Tags: node.js

Есть такой код на node js, который копирует все файлы и папки с помощью `ncp`

```
ncp("\\a", "", function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); 
}
console.log('done!');});
```

Который берет с папки `С:\a` все файлы и папки и копирует у себя.

Вопрос: как мне указать путь вместо `С:\a` расшаренную папку в другом компьютере?

Comment: например \\PC-9234400\app

Comment: пробывал net:\\PC-9234400\app тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так: `"\\\\PC-9234400\\app"`

Дело в том, что в javascript обратная косая черта внутри строкового литерала является спец. символом, и ее надо экранировать. Поэтому внутри строковых литералов символы <kbd>\</kbd> дублируются.